# How do you customize how JAXB generates plural method names?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

We are using JAXB to generate Java classes and have encountered a few cases where generated plural method names are not correct. For example, where we expect `getPhysicians` we are getting `getPhysicien`. How would we customize how JAXB pluralizes specific methods?

The schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="physician">
    <xs:sequence>
       ...
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="physicianList">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Physician"
                    type="physician"
                    minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The generated Java code:

```
...
public class PhysicianList {
...

    @XmlElement(name = "Physician")
    protected List<Physician> physicien;
    ...

    public List<Physician> getPhysicien() {
        if (physicien == null) {
            physicien = new ArrayList<Physician>();
        }
        return this.physicien;
    }
```

---

**Update**

This has been answered by Blaise. However, I prefer not mixing concerns such as JAXB customizations in an XML schema. So for those of you with the same preference, here is a JAXB binding file that achieves the same thing as what Blaise suggested, keeping JAXB customization out of the schema:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               version="2.0">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="myschema.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='physicianList']//xs:element[@name='Physician']">
            <jaxb:property name="physicians"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: It doesn't even spell physician correctly, but rather as physici*e*n. Strange.

Comment: XJC actually bases it on the element name for lists, so you could have just called your element name physicians. BUT (and it is a big but...) if you do this, there is is still a quirk in that when you re-marshal the object using JAXB each element will have the plural name 'physicians'. Very odd. So that said, I have used your approach and it works all round.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

By default the following is generated for your schema fragment:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "physicianList", propOrder = {
        "physician"
    })
    public class PhysicianList {

        @XmlElement(name = "Physician")
        protected List<Physician> physician;

        public List<Physician> getPhysician() {
            if (physician == null) {
                physician = new ArrayList<Physician>();
            }
            return this.physician;
        }

    }
```

If you annotate your XML schema:

```
    <xs:schema
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        jaxb:version="2.1">

        <xs:complexType name="physician">
            <xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:complexType name="physicianList">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Physician"
                            type="physician"
                            minOccurs="0"
                            maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:annotation>
                          <xs:appinfo>
                              <jaxb:property name="physicians"/>
                          </xs:appinfo>
                      </xs:annotation>
                 </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

    </xs:schema>
```

Then you can generate the desired class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "physicianList", propOrder = {
    "physicians"
})
public class PhysicianList {

    @XmlElement(name = "Physician")
    protected List<Physician> physicians;

    public List<Physician> getPhysicians() {
        if (physicians == null) {
            physicians = new ArrayList<Physician>();
        }
        return this.physicians;
    }

}
```

Comment: That worked great. Thanks! FYI, I dislike mixing concerns such as JAXB customizations in an XML schema, so I've added to the end of my question an example of using a binding file to do the same as you suggest. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried the solution suggested by you, and the classes generated still dont have the return types I would love to have. I have asked another question for that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502229/how-do-you-customize-how-jaxb-generates-plural-method-names). I would really appreciate your help if you take your time to answer this question as well.

Answer (score 23):

Maybe it's a little late to answer, but there's another way to generate plural names simply, **without mixing** XML Schema and JAXB Bindings.

By using JAXB XJC binding compiler with the "-extension" mode. 
A customization bindings file need to be added, like this one :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

  <jxb:globalBindings>              
    <xjc:simple/>
  </jxb:globalBindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

References :

- [Experimental simpler&better binding mode](http://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#simple) (**EDIT:** obsolete link)
- [Experimental simpler&better binding mode](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/release-documentation.html#simple) (new link)
- [JAXB: How to change XJC-generated classes names when attr type is specified in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4818344/1677594)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, here's a nice reference on how to pass this bindings file to the xjc on the command line: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ste/10.1?topic=adapter-java-class-requirements

Comment: Basically to use that you would pass two new parameters to xjc "-extension" and "-b bingindgs.xjb" where the contents of bindings.xjb are the contents of the file included in this answer. Works great!