# JAXB and complexType sharing name with one of it's elements generates incorrect code

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

I have this xsd which is kind of bad, but I have to use it to avoid changing the interface of the servlet I’m writing. The xsd for the request-response interface contains the following lines:

```xml
<xs:complexType name=”Foo”>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs=”0” maxOccurs=”unbounded”>
        <xs:element name=”Foo”>
        ...
        </xs:element>
    ...
    </xs:sequence>
<xs:complexType>
```

Notice the name clash. When I use the maven-jaxb-plugin to generate classes from this schema I end up with:

```java
Public class Foo {
...

   public List<Foo.Foo> getFoo() {
   ...
   }

   ...

   public static class Foo {
   ...
   }
}
```

This fails to compile, of course, since it’s not permitted to use the same name on the nested class and the enclosing class. What can I do to solve this, without changing the xsd? I know you can override name by adding tags for jaxb in the xsd. Is it safe to do that? Will it have an impact on the interface of the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an external binding file to customize the generated class names.  For an example see:

- [JAXB: How to change XJC-generated classes names when attr type is specified in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793637/jaxb-how-to-change-xjc-generated-classes-names-when-attr-type-is-specified-in-x/4793999#4793999)

Comment: Awesome! This did the trick. Worth noting is that if you name it with the .xjb extension, maven-jaxb-plugin will automatically take into consideration when generating the classes from the .xsd.