# JAXB complex element and its child with the same name

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin, java-10

Does anybody know how to solve the problem caused by a complex element and its child with the same name?

Env: Ubuntu, Java 10, maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.3

**XSD:**

```
<xs:element name="TheSameName">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="TheSameName">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**BIND.XML**

```
<jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='TheSameName']">
  <jxb:class name="TheSameNameList"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**ERROR:**

***Complex type and its child element share the same name "TheSameName". 
Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.***

With Java 8 was OK but with Java 10 no more :-(   Any idea?

BR, Wianki

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAXB and complexType sharing name with one of it's elements generates incorrect code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297940/jaxb-and-complextype-sharing-name-with-one-of-its-elements-generates-incorrect)

Comment: nullpointer : in my question the parent-name = child-name  (Java8: OK; Java10: NOT)

Comment: Try to customize `/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='TheSameName']/xs:complexType` and/or `/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='TheSameName']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='TheSameName']/xs:complexType`.

Comment: I have already tried that ant with jaxws in jaxb too:
<jaxb:bindings
  <jaxws:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/yxz.xsd">
     <enableWrapperStyle>true</enableWrapperStyle>
     <enableAsyncMapping>false</enableAsyncMapping>
     <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='TheSameName']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='TheSameName']/xs:complexType">
        <jaxb:class name="TheSameNameList"/>
In any case I get the message: "Complex type and its child element share the same name "TheSameName". Use a class customization to resolve this conflict