# Why does JAXB 2 RI's XJC simple mode change collection names?

Tags: java, jaxb, java-metro-framework, jaxb2

JAXB simple binding mode modifies collection names to their plural
'version', e.g. "additionalData" becomes "additionalDatas". Is there any solution to change this behavior? I need to have a Java field name and methods name equal to XSD field name. My bindings file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
version="2.1">
  <globalBindings>
    <serializable uid="1" />
    <xjc:simple/>
  </globalBindings>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 8):

The "simple binding mode" is an extended feature of the JAXB RI (Metro).  Making the collection property names plural was part of its design.

From: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/01/using_jaxb_ris.html

> My favorite feature in the JAXB RI is
>   the simpler and better binding mode,
>   which makes the generated code even
>   easier to use, by ...
>
> 1. Eliminating JAXBElement as much as
>      possible
> 2. Giving you a better, more
>      typed binding in general
> 3. Use plural
>      property names where applicable

You may be able to use the normal schema customizations to control the property name.  Refer to one of my previous answers (link below):

- [How do you customize how JAXB generates plural method names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502229/how-do-you-customize-how-jaxb-generates-plural-method-names/4502572#4502572)

Comment: Is there any way to turn off this feature and keep using "simple binding mode"? Because I need it to add @XmlRootElement to generated classes.

Comment: page http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/01/using_jaxb_ris.html is dead

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20080920034324/http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/01/using_jaxb_ris.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example plugin configuration that leverages the [JAXB2 Simplify Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin#pluralization) which among other things can disable pluralization.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>xjc</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <xjbSources>
        <xjbSource>src/main/resources/jaxb_bindings.xjb</xjbSource>
      </xjbSources>
      <sources>
        <source>${basedir}/schema.xsd</source>
      </sources>
      <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
      <packageName>${groupId}.${artifactId}</packageName>
      <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-Xsimplify-usePluralForm=false</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-plugins</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```