# Java wsimport error

Tags: java, wsimport

I have a web-service and I'm trying to generate java stub classes for it using JDK wsimport. Unfortunately I'm getting errors like "Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class". However, .Net svcutil does the work perfectly.

When digging deeper I found that one of the errors complains on those rows marked with **!!!**:

```
<xs:element name="FilteredQuery">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="identity" nillable="true" type="q1:EphorteIdentity" xmlns:q1="http://..."/>
            !!!<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arguments" nillable="true" type="q2:FilteredQueryArguments" xmlns:q2="http://..."/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
!!!<xs:element name="FilteredQueryArguments" nillable="true" type="q5:FilteredQueryArguments" xmlns:q5="http://..."/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll probably need to deal with a bindings file [xjc two declarations cause a collision in the objectfactory class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422253/xjc-two-declarations-cause-a-collision-in-the-objectfactory-class)