# Dealing with JAXB Collections

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshall the following XML using JAXB:

```
<Works>
    <Work>
        <Composers>
            <Composer>
                <Name>A name</Name>
            </Composer>
            <Composer>
                <Name>A name 2</Name>
            </Composer>
        </Composers>
    </Work>
</Works>
```

I have generated all of the classes using XJC. If I want to access the Composers collection, I have to do this:

```
 List<Composer> composers = work.getComposers().getComposer();
```

Is there any way I can do the following instead?

```
 List<Composer> composers = work.getComposers();
```

I appreciate the need for a Composers object as it derived from the XML, but when dealing in Java, having an intermediate POJO that stores the collections seems a bit redundant.

My XSD is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Works">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Work" type="Work" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Work">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Composers" type="Composers"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Composers">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Composer" type="Composer" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Composer">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Do you have a schema that you used to generate the POJOs?

Comment: List<Composer> composers = work.getComposers().getComposer(); this does not look right. It should return you only one composer not a list of composers . Whereas List<Composer> composers = work.getComposers(); this looks correct .

Comment: @ganguly.sarthak: Although the `work.getComposers().getComposer()` call doesn't *look* right, it is indeed necessary if you're using the generated JAXB classes. I've posted an answer with a link to an XJC plugin that manipulates the generated classes to correct this annoying JAXB quirk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **[@XmlElementWrapper](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin)** plugin does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks William! Unfortunately this plugin doesn't support JAXB 2.1, only 2.0. Is the only option here to downgrade to 2.0?

Comment: I'm using it in a project with JAXB 2.2.3 without any problems. Can you tell me what error you're seeing?

Comment: No error but the generated classes from XJC don't contain the expected @XmlElementWrapper annotations. I am using Java 6 and JAXB 2.1, are you using Java 6 too?

Comment: You're adding xew.jar to the classpath and specifying the "-Xxew" command line option? I just did a quick test with JAXB 2.1 and the XEW plugin, and it generated the @XmlElementWrapper annotations properly. I can write up a step-by-step tutorial if you think it would be helpful.

Comment: William, that would be great!

Comment: Did the step-by-step tutorial every eventuate? It would be really helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the tutorial. I'll put it back on my todo list :-)

Answer (score 3):

For anybody who can not or does not want to use the plugin:
If you can live with a different XML structure, it's possible to avoid generating the extra wrapper classes by simply using `maxoccurs="unbounded"` and leaving out the containing element.  Using the original example:

```
<xsd:element name="Work" type="Work" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>

<xsd:complexType name="Work">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Composer" type="Composer" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Composer">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

will produce a structure like this:

```
<Work>
    <Composer>
        <Name>A name</Name>
    </Composer>
    <Composer>
        <Name>A name 2</Name>
    </Composer>
</Work>
```

This will put a method on the Work type that returns a `List<Composer>` object.  Unfortunately the method is called `getComposer` instead of `getComposers`, but you can use [annotations or custom bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502229/how-do-you-customize-how-jaxb-generates-plural-method-names) to fix that problem.