# How to change the name of Lists generated by JAXB

Tags: jaxb, xsd

I have an xsd that I'm using to generate an object model in Java using JAXB and I want the Lists it generates to be renamed to xyzList instead of xyz. Is there a way to do this without having to add an entry in the bindings file for each list?

For example this xsd fragment:

```
<xs:element name="RegulatoryEL" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

generates this:

```
protected List<RegulatoryEL> RegulatoryEL;
```

but I want something like:

```
protected List<RegulatoryEL> RegulatoryELList;
```

Comment: Except I don't want plural names as thats just a case of adding <xjc:simple/> to my bindings file

Answer (score 0):

JAXB (JSR-222) does not provide a global setting to control how field/property names are generated for elements that can appear multiple times.  Using standard config you will need to do this on a per element basis using an external binding file.

- [How do you customize how JAXB generates plural method names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502229/how-do-you-customize-how-jaxb-generates-plural-method-names/4502572#4502572)

---

To do this in a more general way you could create your own XJC extension:

- http://ricston.com/blog/xjc-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

For manipulate names you can use plugin and register you own name converter. For example look at [xjcnormalize](https://github.com/popofibo/xjcnormalize).

Detailed explanation from their author you may find in this answer: [JAXB convert non-ASCII characters to ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606248/jaxb-convert-non-ascii-characters-to-ascii-characters/21780020#21780020)